# How can I make struct in go for object having array of object inside it?

Tags: vue.js, go

I am using Vuejs on the frontend and Go language on the backend. My `data` variable has data in the following format.

```
var data = {
    software_type: this.$props.selected,
    selected_solutions: this.fromChildChecked,
  };
```

By doing `console.log(data)`in frontend, I get following output.
[image]

On the backend side, I have struct on this format :

```
type Technology struct {
    ID                primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    SoftwareType      string             `json:"software_type" bson:"software_type"`
    SelectedSolutions struct {
        selectedSolutions []string
    } `json:"selected_solutions" bson:"selected_solutions"`
}
```

I am quite sure about the problem that I am having and it might be due to the difference with the format of data that I am sending and the struct that I have made.
I am using MongoDB as a database.
By submitting the form, data comes to DB in the following format, which means, I am getting an empty object for `selected_solutions`.

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5f5a1fa8885112e153b5a890"},
"software_type":"Cross-channel Campain Mangment Software",
"selected_solutions":{}
}
```

This is the format that I expect to be on DB or something similar to below.

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f5a1fa8885112e153b5a890"},
    "software_type":"Cross-channel Campain Mangment Software",
    "selected_solutions":{
         Adobe Campaign: ["Business to Customer (B2C)", "Business to Business (B2B)"],
         Marin Software: ["E-Government", "M-Commerce"],
     }
}
```

How can I change struct to make it compatible with the data that I am trying to send? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT**: This is how I am submitting data.

```
   postUserDetails() {
      var data = {
        software_type: this.$props.selected,
        selected_solutions: this.fromChildChecked,
      };
      console.log(data);
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      };
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/technology", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            if (data.result === "success") {
              //this.response_message = "Registration Successfull";
              console.log("data posted successfully");
            } else if (data.result === "er") {
              //  this.response_message = "Reagestraion failed please try again";
              console.log("failed to post data");
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("error is", error);
        });
    },
    mounted() {
      this.postUserDetails();
    },
```

This is the function for backend controller.

```
//TechnologyHandler handles checkbox selection for technology section
func TechnologyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    var technologyChoices model.Technology
    //var selectedSolution model.Selected
    //reads request body and and stores it inside body
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    //body is a json object, to convert it into go variable json.Unmarshal()is used ,
    //which converts json object to User object of go.
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &technologyChoices)
    var res model.TechnologyResponseResult

    if err != nil {
        res.Error = err.Error()
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)
        return
    }

    collection, err := db.TechnologyDBCollection()
    if err != nil {
        res.Error = err.Error()
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)
        return
    }

    _, err = collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), technologyChoices)
    if err != nil {
        res.Error = "Error While Creating Technology choices, Try Again"
        res.Result = "er"
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)
        return
    }

    res.Result = "success"
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)
    return
}
```

Comment: Burak's suggestion is solid, if it doesn't work for you there's some info missing. Show the actual json being sent to the server.

Comment: @mkopriva I have already posted the format of data I received on Mongo above.

Comment: You misunderstand, I'm talking about the data you are submitting with your vue app. The javascript object in console is irrelevant, the steps taken to submit the request are also irrelevant, what's relevant is what the server receives in the request body, the raw data, the json, capisce?

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistake. I have posted code for that too. Please let me know if there is any mistake.

Comment: That's not what I meant, the raw data, the json, that's the content you're trying to unmarshal, that's what's in the `body` variable that you're passing to `json.Unmarshal`... anyway one can see the missing info in your comment to Burak's answer which suggests that you'll need a slice of slices of string in that map, e.g. `map[string][][]string`, see here: https://play.golang.org/p/-OiaD4Oz-n2

Comment: Thank you. Solved it and understood the format of stuct that I was unknown of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your database structure, `selected_solutions` is an object containing string arrays:

```
type Technology struct {
    ID                primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    SoftwareType      string             `json:"software_type" bson:"software_type"`
    SelectedSolutions map[string][]string `json:"selected_solutions" bson:"selected_solutions"`
}
```

Comment: I have added a form submission code if you think if there is any problem. I couldn't post anything on DB with the solution above.

Comment: How data is submitted depends on the type of `fromChildChecked`.

Comment: `{ "Adobe Campaign": [ [ "Business to Customer (B2C)", "Business to Business (B2B)" ] ], "Marin Software": [ [ "E-Government", "M-Commerce" ] ] }` This is the format for `fromChildChecked`

Comment: You need a map[string][][]string to unmarshal that. You have to process it to match your database structure.

Comment: Thank you, Burak. Solved the problem.